# How to pick currentdate in Jquery Datepicker with phpunit webdriver selenium

Tags: jquery, selenium, datepicker, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

Here's an [example](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) of the datepicker that we use:

( The one in the bottom left )

```
 $search21 = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('csandbox-container'));
 $search21->click();
 // This will open the datepicker.

 // Here I have to select the current date.
```

The datepicker automatically opens on the current month. But how do I select the current date?
Let's say it's the 5th today then I want to select the ' 5 ' if it's the 1th, then it should select the first ofcourse.

If something like this is possible ;/

Thanks in advance

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made these changes and it works. It's not really picking the date but it works.

```
$search21 = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('csandbox-container'));
    $search21->click();

$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('20/10/2014');

sleep(2);

$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys("\xEE\x80\x84");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about php, but in java I did it like:

```
    //after your code, the date picker is already open
    WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"datepicker-days\"]"));
    // get days from this month only, not the overlapping months      
    List<WebElement> dateElements = date.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class=\"day\"]"));

    int i = dateElements.indexOf(new Object() {
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            WebElement element = (WebElement) o;
            return element != null && element.getText().equals("25");  // or whatever day
        }
    });
    dateElements.get(i).click();
```

Good luck in porting this to PHP.

Or even better:

```
WebElement date = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"datepicker-days\"]")));
```

Comment: Hmm thx but yea I don't know about java ;D
Somethings seem familiar trying something at the moment would be nice to get it in php. And to get the currentdate I can just replace the 25 in your example. I will try it out some more today.